# Как установить Debian 11 с overlayfs rootfs?

Tags: linux, установка, загрузка

Устанавливаю Debian 11. Мне надо реализовать следующую схему загрузки:

1.initrd ищет /dev/sda1, который защищён dm-verity, подобно /system в Android:

```
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/system /mnt/ro
```

2.initrd монтирует writable часть:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/rw
```

3.initrd монтирует ramfs и копирует туда корневую ФС, чтобы она далее могла работать без внешнего носителя (boot-to-ram):

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=$(rootfs-size) tmpfs /mnt/root-ram
cp -r /mnt/ro /mnt/rw
umount /mnt/ro
restorecon -R /mnt/root-ram
```

4.initrd монтирует overlayfs

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/root-ram,upperdir=/mnt/rw /mnt/new-root
```

5.И корень переключается на overlayfs:

```
exec switch_root /mnt/new-root /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Как её реализовать при установке системы? (boot схема - BIOS/Legacy Boot)

Comment: так вам нужно инитрд свой писать

Comment: все бы ничего, но как написать под дебиан? Как бы подстраиваться под уже существующий дистрибутив довольно тяжело...

Comment: Там есть хуки. Нужно вставить между маунтом и свичрутом вашу логику. Для начала распакуй рамдиск и посмотри там скрипт инит.